# Reducing the border radius on a Gooey Toggle button?

Tags: css

I'm attempting to mimic this toggle (current not a true toggle just elements animated to do the sort of interaction I'm trying) and have a preliminary version done but the border radius between the Ball and line isn't quite right.

This is the initial dribble design we saw and enjoyed: https://dribbble.com/shots/2028065-Switcher-lll?list=users&offset=2

and this is my initial attempt: http://codepen.io/mhsenkow/pen/eNMqeb

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Curious if people have thoughts?